# Ubuntu 14.04 & remote desktop

Tags: 14.04, remote

Till now I'm working with ubuntu 12.04 on a standalone pc (no display,mouse,keyboard).

I installed xrdp and i'm using windows remote desktop connection.

It's working fine with juste one adjustment : put that in the .xsession

```
gnome-session --session=ubuntu-2d
```

This morning I tried installing ubuntu 14.04, xrdp, .xsession adjustment and ... no working anymore.  Only a grey screen with a X mouse cursor.

After lot of search and reading on internet it seems it's not more possible to use ubuntu-2d with 14.04.  Only xfce is working.  But I don't want to use xfce !

So what's the solution ?

- xrdp with windows remote connection : works only with xfce
- teamviewer : it's working but everything I do is visible on the server (if a screen is connected) and the session remains open if I do not logout before I quit teamviewer client (so someone can connect a keyboard to the server and use it)
- x2go : seems not working fine with 14.04
- desktop sharing : not working.  I'm using ultravnc and I got No security type suitable for RFB 3.3 supported
- ... ?

It's so easy with windows ... The only thing I want is to connect to my server, open a remote session and work.  Is it impossible mission ?

Answer (score 0):

I use remmina without problems, have you tried that?

I like it as it stores all my servers settings so I can simply switch from one to another.

Comment: No, didn't know remmina.  Just have a look on internet.  But I don't understand.  It's only a client ?  If so what server do you use ?  And I think it's not possible for my 'main' pc running under windows.

Comment: @tweetysat AFAIK, the default Ubuntu desktop comes with Vino (or at least enabling desktop sharing in the Sharing settings enables it). Vino is good enough VNC server.

Answer (score 0):

can i recommend lubuntu(14.04.5); tested working vith virtualbox

```
apt-get install xrdp
nano /etc/xrdp/startwm.sh > last line . /etc/X11/Xsession
home folder > show hidden > .xsession > add any of the 3 following lines
    lxsession -e LXDE -s Lubuntu
    lxsession -e LXDM -s Lubuntu
    lxsession -s Lubuntu
service xrdp restart(..not required)
```

you can change various xrdp settings

```
nano /etc/xrdp/xrdp.ini 
service xrdp restart
```

[How to Remote Desktop from Windows to Lubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/580415/how-to-remote-desktop-from-windows-to-lubuntu)

seems ubuntu(14-16) is bugged regarding any rdp as it requires hardware acceleration

[[bugs] gnome-session is broken without 3d acceleration](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-session/+bug/1274013)

[[bugs] gnome-session-flashback/Unity fails to start without hardware acceleration](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-session/+bug/1251281)

Answer (score -1):

from ubuntu 12.10 ~

```
gnome-session --session=ubuntu-2d
gnome-session --session=gnome-fallback
```

use hardware accelerator...
Does not support