# How to Remote Desktop from Windows to Lubuntu

Tags: windows, lubuntu, xrdp

I have tried to use the `xrdp` to remotely connect from Windows to Lubuntu. I have tried several ways and have followed several guides but nothing worked. 
When trying to connect from Windows I am asked for username and password. I enter them but the only thing that is displayed is some kind of gray screen and the cursor is just an cross. Nothing happens after that.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

First open a terminal and enter `sudo apt-get install xrdp`. 
When that is installed enter `sudo nano /etc/xrdp/startwm.sh` in the terminal. 
Make sure the last line looks like this:

`. /etc/X11/Xsession`

Then go to your home folder, rightclick and select `Show hidden`. 
If there is no file named `.xsession`, create it. If there is a filed named like that, open it and make sure that it looks like this when your done: `lxsession -e LXDE -s Lubuntu`

Now type `sudo service xrdp restart` in the terminal to restart xrdp. Now it should work :)

Comment: I have to tell you that I always come back to this answer after re-setting up my server. I'm so glad that you wrote this!

Comment: My last line looks like this: exec /bin/sh /etc/X11/Xsession and it's working too .. just a bit different call.

Comment: On my old A/Open Digital Engine (Intel 945GM Express Chipset) with Lubuntu 18.04 this works, but it breaks Xorg on the console.