# remote Desktop on raspberrypi not working

Tags: remote-desktop

I Installed Ubuntu  on raspberry pi and installed remote Desktop by the following command

```
apt-get install xrdp
```

but it Does not work  whenever i try to connect it  shows a black screen and turns off would anyone help ? thanks in advance

i installed ubuntu server from here :

from here [ubuntu-18.04.3-desktop-amd64](https://ubuntu.com/download/raspberry-pi)

[image]

More Details about the Pi i am running :

```
processor       : 0
BogoMIPS        : 38.40
Features        : fp asimd evtstrm crc32 cpuid
CPU implementer : 0x41
CPU architecture: 8
CPU variant     : 0x0
CPU part        : 0xd03
CPU revision    : 4

processor       : 1
BogoMIPS        : 38.40
Features        : fp asimd evtstrm crc32 cpuid
CPU implementer : 0x41
CPU architecture: 8
CPU variant     : 0x0
CPU part        : 0xd03
CPU revision    : 4

processor       : 2
BogoMIPS        : 38.40
Features        : fp asimd evtstrm crc32 cpuid
CPU implementer : 0x41
CPU architecture: 8
CPU variant     : 0x0
CPU part        : 0xd03
CPU revision    : 4

processor       : 3
BogoMIPS        : 38.40
Features        : fp asimd evtstrm crc32 cpuid
CPU implementer : 0x41
CPU architecture: 8
CPU variant     : 0x0
CPU part        : 0xd03
CPU revision    : 4

Hardware        : BCM2835
Revision        : a02082
Serial          : 000000009c800ff0
Model           : Raspberry Pi 3 Model B Rev 1.2
```

Comment: i have installed it using the command apt-get install lubuntu-desktop

Comment: Does this question answer your question? [How to Remote Desktop from Windows to Lubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/580415/how-to-remote-desktop-from-windows-to-lubuntu)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

done it from the below links:

[here](http://catch22cats.blogspot.com/2018/05/xrdp-blank-screen-with-ubuntu-1804.html) 
and 
[here](https://github.com/neutrinolabs/xrdp/issues/1358)

> If you are trying to use remote desktop on Ubuntu or Xubuntu 18.04 you
>   may find that after logging in all you see is a blank screen.
>
> One cause of this is that xfce4 has added code that prevents a second
>   session from opening. You will find that if your computer's main
>   screen is logged into xfce4 you may not be able to use it with xrdp.
>
> To solve this "second session" problem and allow as many sessions as
>   you need, edit /etc/xrdp/startwm.sh and add these lines before the
>   lines that test and execute Xsession. The $HOME/.profile is not part
>   of the solution, but is something that should be run before starting
>   the session anyway.
>
> ```
> unset DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS  
> unset XDG_RUNTIME_DIR  
> . $HOME/.profile
> ```

Comment: It may also be that you're trying to login with remote desktop using your root account on the pi.  You should try creating another user on the pi, and add that user to the ssl-cert group, and try logging in with that new account.  
https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-xrdp-on-raspberry-pi/